# Usar várias condição ternária no php

Tags: php, lógica

Como usar várias condição ternária, na mesma linha?

Exemplo:

```
echo ($estado == 'SP' ? 'São Paulo' : ($estado == 'RJ' ? 'Rio de Janeiro') : ($estado == 'PR' ? 'Paraná') : 'teste');
```

Desse jeito está dando erro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Até é possível usar isso mas, como você pode perceber, a legibilidade do código fica horrível.

"*Identando*" a condição dá pra ver onde está o erro (no controle dos parênteses):

```
echo
($estado == 'SP' ? 
   'São Paulo' : 
   ($estado == 'RJ' ? 
      'Rio de Janeiro') : 
      ($estado == 'PR' ? 'Paraná') : 
          'teste');
```

A montagem correta ficaria assim:

```
echo
($estado == 'SP' ? 
   'São Paulo' : 
   ($estado == 'RJ' ? 
      'Rio de Janeiro' : 
      ($estado == 'PR' ?
          'Paraná' : 
          'teste')
    )
 );

//em uma linha só:
echo ($estado == 'SP' ? 'São Paulo' : ($estado == 'RJ' ? 'Rio de Janeiro' : ($estado == 'PR' ? 'Paraná' : 'teste')));
```

**lembrando**: em casos com mais de uma validação, é mais interessante usar *if* ou *switch*.

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado!